# The effect of policy parameter on the action and the state distribution in policy gradient method for episodic tasks

Tags: policy-gradient

In the second edition of the book "Reinforcement Learning: an introduction" by Sutton and Bato page 324 (Policy gradient chapter):
It says that:
Given a state, the effect of the policy parameter on the actions, and thus on reward, can be computed in a relatively straightforward way from knowledge of the parameterization. But the effect of the policy on the state distribution is a function of the environment and is typically unknown.

Can anyone explain why it is straightforward for actions and why it is unknown for state distribution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@AliGh What the author means by "the effect of the policy on the state distribution is a function of the environment and is **typically** unknown" is that to compute the state distribution besides the policy you also require transition model of the environment and this transition model is **usually** unknown.

Chelsea Finn derives a dynamic programming algorithm to compute state distribution on blackboard in lecture 10b of deep rl bootcamp. You can look at it for further clarification.

Lecture 10b of deep rl bootcamp
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9DlQSJQAoI&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

If you have a neural network policy $\pi_\theta(\cdot | s)$, you can compute the effect of $\theta$ on $\pi$ simply by doing a single forward pass of the network. On the other hand, there is no easy way to compute the distribution of states given that your agent is following the policy $\pi_\theta$. Just try to think of how you would compute it -- there's no good way.

Comment: But my problem is that what is the point of the author when it says the effect of policy on the state distribution is unknown? Because state distribution is about environment and policy is what agent does, so affecting the environment by the agent cannot happen.

Comment: "Because state distribution is about environment". No, the state distribution is a function of **both** the environment and the agent

Comment: Based on what you say, the agent should have the power to change the environment. Can you give me an example or reference for more details?

Comment: Consider an environment with three states, left, middle, and right, and each episode starts with the agent in the middle state. The agent has two actions, L and R, which move the agent to the left / right state respectively. The state distribution for an policy which always takes the L action is obviously different from the state distribution of a policy which always takes the R action.

Comment: @AliGh if you mean "the state" by environment, then yes. If you mean the underlying MDP, then no, an agent cannot change that.